# Find mean and covariance of transitional distribution from prior to posterior

Tags: statistics

suppose $p(\mathbf{x}) \sim{}N(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{m},\mathbf{P})$ is the prior density, where $\mathbf{m}$ is mean, and $\mathbf{P}$ is covariance. $l(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})\sim{}N(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Hx},\mathbf{R})$ is the likelihood, where $\mathbf{H}$ is a linear transform, now make

$$\phi(\mathbf{x},\gamma|\mathbf{y})=\frac{l(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})p(\mathbf{x})^{\gamma}}{\int_{\mathbf{x}}l(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})p(\mathbf{x})^{\gamma}},   \qquad(1)$$

where $\gamma\in(0,1]$, $\phi(\mathbf{x},\gamma)$ is also a density, and can be regared as the transitional density from prior to posterior when $\gamma$ change from $0\sim{}1$, I want to get the mean and covariance of the density $\phi(\mathbf{x},\gamma)$ as functions of $\gamma$ in close form,is this possible? 
My work so far:
I think the equation above can be treated as a progressive Bayesian formula,and 
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x}, \gamma|\mathbf{y}) = 
\frac{l(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})
g(\mathbf{x},\gamma)}{\int_{\mathbf{x}}{l(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{x},\gamma)}}, \quad g(\mathbf{x},\gamma)=\frac{p(\mathbf{x})^{\gamma}}{\int_{\mathbf{x}}p(\mathbf{x})^{\gamma}} \qquad (2)
$$
I've proved that under one dimension condition,the following is true,

$$g(x,\gamma)=\frac{p(x)^{\gamma}}{\int_{x}p(x)^{\gamma}}\sim{}N(m,P/\gamma),$$ now, if the equation above can be generalized to multivariant gaussian, $\phi(\mathbf{x},\gamma|\mathbf{y})$ is also a Bayesian formula for two gaussian density $l(x|y)$ and $g(x,\gamma)$,

and the mean and covariance of $\phi(x,\gamma|y)$ as function of $\gamma$ can be derived by lemmas of joint density and conditional density of Gaussian variable,

now the problem is, I want to have some consistency with (1), but (2) have no definition when $\gamma = 0$.

anyone can help me proceed please?

Comment: The conditional density $l(y\mid x)$ is soon replaced by $l(x)$. Please explain.

Comment: $l(y|x)$ is the likelihood regarded as function of x,I'm very sorry for my expression

Comment: Then $\phi(x,\gamma)$ also depends on $y$. Please explain.

Comment: I've updata my progress, sorry for my expression, I will try my best to make it clear,